# I am trying to add together elements from a list but keep getting a weird number

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to add several elements in a list together and determine which list has the largest sum, but one of the functions always returns a large negative number like -13168. If it helps the first function always works, even when I switch the order in which they are read. I believe it is a problem with how the the variable are read by the compiler, but I don't have enough experience to fully understand what is going wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    //initiates variables and array
    int array1[5];
    int array2[5];
    int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    int sum1, sum2;

//These first two loops are used to collect data from the user
    for(a = 0; a < 5; a++){
        printf("Please input an integer into the first list: ");
        scanf("%d", &array1[a]);
        }

    for(b = 0; b < 5; b++){
        printf("Please input an integer into the first second: ");
        scanf("%d", &array2[b]);

        }
//returns info from the first list
    printf("Your first list contains:");
    for(c = 0; c < 5; c++){
        printf("%d", array1[c]);
    }

//returns info from the second list
    printf("\nYour second list contains:");
    for(d = 0; d < 5; d++){
        printf("%d", array2[d]);
    }

//adds up elements within list 1
    for(e = 0; e < 5; e++){
        sum1 = sum1 + array1[e];
    }

//adds up elements within list 2
    for(f = 0; f < 5; f++){
        sum2 = sum2 + array2[f];
    }
    

    printf("\n%d", sum1);
    printf("\n%d", sum2);
//compares each list size and determines which is the largest
    if (sum1 > sum2){
        printf("\nYour first list is larger ( %d > %d )", sum1, sum2);
    }
    else{
        printf("\nYour second list is larger ( %d < %d )", sum1, sum2);
    }

        return 0;
    }
```

Edit

I forgot to add the output when the code is used. The first 10 lines are input from the user. I am using the cygwin terminal to run the code and sublime to edit it.

Please input an integer into the first list: 1
Please input an integer into the first list: 1
Please input an integer into the first list: 1
Please input an integer into the first list: 1
Please input an integer into the first list: 1
Please input an integer into the first second: 2
Please input an integer into the first second: 2
Please input an integer into the first second: 2
Please input an integer into the first second: 2
Please input an integer into the first second: 2
Your first list contains:11111
Your second list contains:22222
5
-13078
Your first list is larger ( 5 > -13078 )

Comment: You need to initialize your variables (e.g. `int sum1=0, sum2=0;`. Try enabling warnings from your compiler.

Comment: when you don't initialize sum = 0, the sum variable may contain a garbage value. Garbage value is a waste or unused value which are available in memory during the declaration of variables. And an additional tip you don't have to use multiple variables to for loop such as a,b,c,d,e,f.  one variable can do the job for every for loop(not nested).

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize variables with some value to avoid them holding "trash".

In your code sum1 and sum2 don't start with a determined value so they can have some random "trash" value. You can initialize them with 0 to avoid this problem.

```
int sum1=0, sum2=0;
```